# Ace jump with different languages

Tags: emacs

I can't figure out why ace-jump wouldn't work with different input method.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I've made it for input-method `russian-computer`, see https://github.com/boykov/ace-jump-mode/compare/l10n-russian

---

Upd. If somebody wants to adopt this code for another language, he should modify it in three aspects:

```
(set-input-method 'russian-computer)
```

use required input-method here. Second:

```
(eq x 63) (eq x 47)
(number-sequence 35 122)
```

chose respective numbers here. Third:

```
eab/char-en-ru
```

make sure that hash-table for another pair of languages is created correctly.

Comment: how do I use it? Should I just replace ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ace-jump-mode-20140616.115/ace-jump-mode.el? That doesn't sound right, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you should just replace the file. Also you should have russian keyboard for testing and keep in mind that modified ace-jump works for english and russian input methods at the same time.

Comment: but what happens when Emacs decides to update the package, wouldn't it be overwritten?

Comment: for some reason it didn't work on my configuration. I guess it has something to do with evil-mode. I'll try to find why it's not working

Comment: 1) I just use my own github repo and emacs updates the package from there.

Comment: 2) It isn't the problem with my code but with your emacs config, sorry. It just works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68325/discussion-between-artscan-and-agzam).